# Mix Element with Class Selector in Same CSS Rule

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to mix `element` selectors with `class` selectors? In other words:

```
<h1 class="header">Hello, World!</h1>

h1 .header {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Keep in mind that white-space matters in this case.

- `h1 .header` will target some element with class `header` that is a descendant of an `h1` tag. The descendant combinator (ie. the space) is not a preferred way of handling css descendants if it can be avoided since it can eat up loading resources.
- `h1.header` targets only `h1` elements with the class of `header`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No space between the 2 selectors.

```
h1.header { /* something; */ }
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax_element_class